# Jquery trigger on keypress

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am Using wordpress as cms

I have made a code which Runs a     like()   function when i press the left key
i try to trigger .love in like() Function 
but it doesnt works

Here is my Code

```
 var h2top = 0;
  function like(){
scrollTop = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
jQuery('.container .post').each(function(i, h2){ /* loop through article headings */

    h2top = jQuery(h2).offset().top ; /* get article heading top */

    if (scrollTop<h2top-19) { /* compare if document is below heading */
      alert("Ram");
        jQuery(this).find('.love').trigger( "click" );
        return false; /* exit function */
    }
});
}
```

Here is the jquery code for Keypress events

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
$(document.documentElement).keyup(function (event) {
var direction = null;

// handle cursor keys
if (event.keyCode == 37) {
// go left
like();
$("#sad").closest('div').addClass('left');
alert("left");
} else if (event.keyCode == 39) {
// go right
alert("right");
}


});
});
```

Just using alert() to check whether the code is running or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
  alert (1);
  // use event.which instead of keyCode
});
```

Instead of

```
$(document.documentElement).keyup(function (event) {
```

Other error, in your like function at the line `jQuery(this).find('.love').trigger( "click" );`

`this` is not the jQuery context, you must use `$(this)` like

```
jQuery($(this)).find('.love').trigger( "click" );
```

Example (updated)

http://jsbin.com/azUnUlO/1/

Comment: I think u read the question in wrong way.. if i use .html() instead of trigger It works